# GitHub Actions - more than one cron

Tags: github, github-actions

According to [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#scheduled-events), I can use the following syntax for running the CI on a schedule:

```yaml
on:
  schedule:
    # * is a special character in YAML so you have to quote this string
    - cron:  '*/15 * * * *'
```

What if I want two crons? What's the syntax for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add a cron definiton below the first

```yaml
on:
  schedule:
    # * is a special character in YAML so you have to quote this string
    - cron: '0 * * * *'
    - cron: '*/10 5 * * *'
```

Comment: will all the jobs defined in the script run on both these schedules? Or, can I customize which jobs follow which cron?

Answer (score 5):

Responding to [@Nasif's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1445015/nasif-imtiaz-ohi) question on the accepted answer:

> will all the jobs defined in the script run on both these schedules? Or, can I customize which jobs follow which cron?

Yes, I believe they will. However, if you want to run different tasks on different cron's, you can do the following (from the [GH Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule)):

```yaml
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '30 5 * * 1,3'
    - cron: '30 5 * * 2,4'

jobs:
  test_schedule:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Not on Monday or Wednesday
        if: github.event.schedule != '30 5 * * 1,3'
        run: echo "This step will be skipped on Monday and Wednesday"
      - name: Every time
        run: echo "This step will always run"
```